# Netbeans 6.9 UNDO operations

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I am using Netbeans 6.9. I have made lots of changes and commit Save file. But, now I want to undo all. Anybody help me how can I do this or is it possible or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually Netbeans allows you to undo using the usual `Ctrl-Z` key combination, but that has it's own limits. Since you said the you `committed` I would assume that you are using some source version control such as SVN. If that is the case, you should still be able to revert the file you have changed to a previous revision (assuming that the file had a previous revision) through your source control.

Comment: Sorry, but how to use source control ?

Comment: @alessandro Source Control are programs such as SVN which allow you to commit code to a repository. Every time you commit something, you can revert it back to any other revision. This is not something offered by Netbeans. I assumed you had some sort of version control when you mentioned the word `commited`